# Add WooCommerce customer data into database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I think this is a long shot but does anyone know how i can automatically add customerdata into my database after they have succesfully made an order via WooCommerce?

I now get a confirmation e-mail with the customer data and I have to insert the data manually into the database. I think some function triggers the e-mail and puts the information in the e-mail, but I can't figure out where this file/function is located.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What data are you manually inserting? Do you have guest-checkout enabled? If so, then customers do not have to create an account. If disabled, customers must create accounts and then all their data will be saved to their user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found it! This works with guest checkouts as well. In the file woocommerce > includes > api > class-wc-api-orders.php I found al the properties of '$order'.

After that, I made a new template of the e-mail I receive after the order is submitted via the the wordpress dashboard: Woocommerce > E-mails > New order > Template. On that page, Woocommerce gives the path of the template php file. In this php file, I added some code to add all the order properties in the database.

Comment: This answer does not seem to correspond to your question at all.

Comment: This is the story: I sell a software product on my website. To use this product, people need to have an account for that product. Those accounts are stored in an online database.

Comment: ...If someone buys an account via my website, I had to insert the data manually in the account database of the software product.

I inserted the account data after I got a 'New Order'mail. This mail is of course sent automatically after an order, so I thought that it should be possible to automatically insert the data into my other database. To do that, I wanted to change the php file that sends the 'New Order' mail.

I had two problems: I didn't know wich php code was responsible for sending the 'New Order' mail and I didn't know where the customer data was stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in your postmeta table. I found mine in that table.

```
SELECT * FROM wpp8_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_billing_email'
```